# Is accessing database directly in the controller an antipattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, abstraction

Is:

```
public ActionResult Whatever(int id) `
{
  using (var db = new Context()) 
  {
     var result = db.Whatevers.Where(x => x.Id == id);
     // ....
  }
}
```

bad approach and I should lean towards adding layer of abstraction like some kind of Repository (f.e. implementing an interface)?

Something like:

```
var repo = new MyRepository(db) // context created earlier
var result = repo.GetWhatever(id);
```

Is there some general rule that I'm missing?
Or does it depend on the complexity of the logic inside of the controller.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is generally a good practice to abstract your database interactions into a separate layer. It is also good practice to always access the resources via an Interface and using dependency inject to resolve the instances of those objects at runtime.

There is no hard and fast rule on this but in professional environments no one is going to be creating an application with data access logic in their controller.

Comment: Also, I think, it allows better testing (thanks to loose coupling you can mock the repository etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors,

1. Is the size of the your application is not very small?
2. Are you going to use the logic for website only? Mobile application
3. What would change in time? Are you going to change the storage? Are you going to use the same logic across controller actions?
4. Are you going to cover your code with unit/integration tests?

Accessing database in the controller would be OK if answers on all these question are **NO**. Otherwise consider using things below, depending on the complicity of you application

1. [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
2. IOC containers, like [Autofac](http://autofac.org/)
3. [Repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)
4. [Unit of work pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)